# How to implement a for loop with if statements

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, if-statement

```
for (let i = 0 ; i<user.length;i++)

{

     if (this.username === user[i].username && this.password === user[i].password){
       this.title="Successfully login your account";
       this.router.navigate(['/home']);
       return;     
     } else {
      this.title = "Please check your username and password (or) create New Account in Register";  
      return;
     }

     }

    return user[i];

}
```

Comment: Use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) instead if you are using `angularjs`

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? It also looks like you have an extra curly bracket in your code, can you remove that and confirm there is still a problem?

Comment: sorry, but this code is a mess. you have an extra "}" brace, you are returning 2 different data types (which you do not want to do) and your else and return statements should not be in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

your else statement should not be in the loop. you else statement will execute as soon as you hit the first user. set a userVerifiedFlg = false; before the loop, and then check to see if it is still false after checking against all users.